# How to produce custom 500 Error JSON response in Laravel 8 API

Tags: nginx, laravel-8

I have created a project using Laravel 8, Redis, Nginx and hosted in a Linux server.
The work Flow is `Request -> Nginx -> Php-fpm -> Laravel 8 -> Nginx-> Response`

Now, When my Redis server is turned off or non-reachable, I get:
 `local.CRITICAL: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`
And it loops indefinitely and runs into PHP Fatal error: Allowed Memory size exhausted.

Now my question is that, even if I try reconnection only to a fixed time and fix this error, How can I handle Memory Exhausted error or any type of unhandled error in Laravel 8 or Via Nginx to produce a custom 500 JSON Response instead of default one.

> Note: Also added a 500 json response in nginx config file and that is not returned incase of 500 Error.

Comment: Can you please share your nginx configuration? The `error_page` directive should work in case your Laravel App returns a HTTP500 in case of such unhandeled exceptions. Does it do it?

Comment: Yeah, Other error_pages seems to work. But the errors like fatal error doesn't seem to be handled.
The code block in nginx config is:
`error_page 500 /500.json;`
        `location /500.json {`
               `add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json charset=UTF-8';`
               `return 500 '{"status": "failure-test","status_code": 500,"date_time": "$date_gmt","detail": "Internal Server Error"}';}`

Comment: Does your Laravel app return a HTTP 500 Status code? You just verify that? Can you share the nginx configuration as well, please.